# operating system not found after installing skin pack

Tags: windows-xp

i has installing a excutable file from skin pack — I believe it was the windows 8 skinpack final (win xp). i am using window xp

And now his operating system won't start (Windows xp).

It gets to the BIOS and then goes to load up the OS but the screen goes blank and it just goes back to the BIOS over and over again. He decided to play with the bootup settings and tried different options and got the error message "Operating System not found."

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Change the BIOS settings back to what they were originally (so you don't get the "Operating System not found" message), then try booting Windows in safe mode by pressing F8 while the BIOS starts to load Windows. (You might need to press it repeatedly or hold it down.)

If you can boot into safe mode, you might be able to use System Restore to get normal boot working again.

If you can't boot into safe mode, or if you can't use System Restore, try booting from the Windows CD (if you have one) and using its repair feature. See the instructions here: http://www.geekstogo.com/forum/topic/138-how-to-repair-windows-xp/